# r shiny leaflet - creating popups one by one 'on demand'

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Inserting popups in `addCirclemarkers` caused lengthy calculation time for data of thousands of points to be mapped. I am assuming all popups have to be calculated before showing the map.

I searched online for a way to only add/create the popup if a point/circle/marker is clicked. Currently, I am at the below code. If you run this code, you will see that the popup is created, but the string to extract from the data is not shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(sp)

data <- data.frame(
  "name"=c("Place 1","Place 2","Place 3"),
  "lat"=c(50,51,52),
  "lng"=c(3,4,5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(8, offset = 2, leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "650px")))
  )                             

server = function(input, output, session) {

  pts <- reactive({
    pts <- data
    coordinates(pts) <- ~lng+lat
    pts
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(pts()) %>%
      addTiles(group="OSM") %>%
      addCircleMarkers()
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    leafletProxy("map") %>% clearPopups()
    event <- input$map_marker_click
    if (is.null(event))
      return()
    isolate({
      pts2 <- pts()
      sgh <- pts2[row.names(pts2) == event$id,]
      # sgh <- pts2[pts2$name == event$id,]
      content <-  htmlEscape(paste("This place is",as.character(sgh$name)))
      leafletProxy("map") %>% addPopups(event$lng, event$lat, content, layerId = event$id)
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you code `event$id` is `NULL`, so the `sgh <- pts2[row.names(pts2) == event$id,]` line return `NULL` as well.

You have to add the `layerId` to the `CircleMarkers` (and is not necessary to add it to the `Popup`.
This also let access it wothout needing to 'merge' it with the original data:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(pts()) %>%
        addTiles(group="OSM") %>%
        addCircleMarkers(layerId = ~name)
})

observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    leafletProxy("map") %>% 
        clearPopups()
    event <- input$map_marker_click
    if (is.null(event))
        return()
    isolate({
        content <-  htmlEscape(paste("This place is", event$id))

        leafletProxy("map") %>% 
            addPopups(event$lng, event$lat, content)
    })
})
```

Comment: Then you probably need to 'merge' to the original data, just like you did before. (`event$id` now contains the `name` values of the original data)

Comment: Many thanks! What if I want to use more data in the popup, e.g. if there would be a third column in the data, like  "type"= c("great","far away","popular")? How could I then show "This is place Place 1 and it is really great".?

Comment: Seems you replied before I deleted my earlier comment. ;)

Comment: So event$id always takes the first column of the original data?

Comment: it takes the value specified in the `addCircleMarkers`'s `layerId` argument

Comment: Perfect! I am not going to confess how long it took me to sort this out, but you made my day.